# Validate only if not changed

Tags: laravel

I have a user settings form with 4 fields - first and last name, date of birth and username. The username is unique field in the database. The issue that I run into is when I already have set your username but after that want to update the last name or first name it always throws an error that the username is already in use. Can I somehow check if the username hasn't been changed to not validate it? Only to validate the other fields?

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $this->portfolioValidator($request->all())->validate();

    $user->username = $request->username;
    $user->contact->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->contact->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->contact->save();

    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'The changes have been saved'], 201);
}

protected function portfolioValidator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:30', 'unique:users'],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your `unique` rule to ignore the current user as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique):

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

protected function portfolioValidator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:30', Rule::unique('users')->ignore(Auth::user()->id)],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: that won't work, because the user might still want to change his username and then it will have to validated. The point is to ignore the validation if the username coming from the form is the same as it is in the database now.

Comment: Well, this does exactly that. You have 2 cases: 

1.username in db is same as form data, then because we are ignoring the current user the validation rule will pass, and we know that this is the only user with that username ( supposedly you have an UNIQUE key on your table)

2. username in db is different from form data, then if there is another user EXCEPT the current one with that username (we already handled case 1), it will fail, which is the desired behaviour from what i understand. The other fields should be validated as usual, no changes there.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right. I just though it will always ignore the logged user lol